# How to store a big set of data into an array in C

Tags: c

I have a data file named somedata.dat, it contains a list of number pairs. about 10000 pairs. Like this:

```
3 19
5 213
1 34
7 93
```

I try to open the file, and read them, then put the numbers in a 10000x2 array. However, with the following code, it stops running when the loop hits about the 80000th time (needless to say EOF). Any ideas? Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int data[10000][2];
FILE *fp;

char s[5];
char temp[2];
char cur;
char next;
int pid=0;
int k=0;

fp = fopen("c:\\somedata.dat","r");
while (!EOF)
{
    cur = fgetc(fp);
    if (cur==' ')
    {           
        data[pid][0]=atoi(s);
        memset(&s[0], 0, sizeof(s));
    }
    else if (cur=='\n')
    {
        data[pid][1]=atoi(s);
        pid++;
        memset(&s[0], 0, sizeof(s));
    }
    else
    {
        temp[0]=cur;
        temp[1]='\0';
        strcat(s,temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (k!=80000)` -- are you certain you didn't _ask_ for it to stop working?

Comment: im in no way C expert. but such big arrays should be in the heap.
malloc it.

Comment: You should use heap allocated arrays (with `calloc`) to deal with large data sets.

Comment: You are not handling the return value of `fgetc` properly.

Comment: You should indent your code to better find matching brackets.

Comment: sorry correction, it should be (!EOF).

Comment: Hi Nahum, How do I malloc it? could you show some sample code? sorry i'm not good at C

Comment: And you read single chars but want to read multiple chars at once like "213". Have you tested your code with a smaller file?

Comment: 10000*2 = 20000 * sizeof(int), let us suppose 8, gives 160k, which is a ridiculous size (though, it may be still better to store it in the heap)

Comment: Yes smaller file works, it's just once the loop runs over about 80000 times, it stuck.

Comment: Hi ShinTakezou, could you show me how to declare this as 2-dimentional array with a sample code? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array can be established and stored. However using malloc does make more sense. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:***

You define an array of 20,000 and try to add aprox 10,000 paris, and it stops at 80,000?

Would guess it is, since you have no break in the loop, it reads 10,000, then read EOF 70,000 times + do some strange stuff to the array. Then exits.

---

You have to compare `EOF` to something.

Typically:

```
int c; /* Has to be int, not char */

while((c = fgetc(fh)) != EOF) {

   ...
}
```

---

Also; take a look at [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/), from stdio.h. Perhaps better suited for your usage.

---

As well; `fgetc()` retrieve *one* and *one* *int* representable as *char* or EOF.

I.e. File:

```
12 33
16 693
```

Then fgetc would retrieve:

```
1: '1'
2: '2'
3: ' '
4: '3'
5: '3'
6: '\n'
7: '1'
8: '6'
...
```

---

Further: Check when you use functions. If fgetc() return EOF, then you are either at EOF ***or*** a read error occurred. Check with feror etc.

---

Comment: Thanks, But do you know how to optimize the code so it does not stuck once the loop goes over 80000 times? thanks!

Comment: I would say, he *must* use fscanf in his case.

Comment: there's no intrinsic "80000" limits in that code. It will stop when the file will end (beware of buffer overflow)

Comment: @eastboundr If you have a file of 10,000 lines, and an array of 20,000 - You do not want to keep adding/reading after EOF. Or have I missed something here?

Comment: @user120115: use `feof(fh)` as a terminating condition of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have written:

```
while (k!=80000)
```

Might be the reason to stop at 80.000

Comment: EOF is a constant, what is it's value? You should compare EOF with the data read.

Comment: well, I just try to make the while loop reach the end of file... I thought !EOF does it...

Comment: When better use while(true) to avoid confusion. (or while(1))

Comment: @eastboundr EOF isn't a function, but a constant. If EOF is i.e. -1, then while(!EOF) would mean while (!-1) , or always false.